# cannot create directory tns_modules

Tags: node.js, xcode, typescript, npm, nativescript

I have a problem with running demo application im Nativescript.

I run:

```
tns run ios
```

And have error:

> Unable to apply changes on device: DEVICE_ID. Error is: Processing
>   node_modules failed. Error: cp: cannot create directory '/workspace/demo/platforms/ios/demo/app/tns_modules':
>   No such file or directory.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For what command u got this error?

Comment: Sorry for that. I edited post few minutes ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I have bad nodejs verion. After remove whole packages and install **node6** (which has LTS)! Everything works.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem too, after recloning a local copy of a dependency.

What fixed this for me was changing the permissions of the .git folder:

```
chmod -R 777 .git
```